# symfony2 application, vagrant & ant: stty: standard input: Invalid argument

Tags: php, ant, symfony, phpunit, stty

I am trying to move my development environment (symfony2 application) from my windows 7 localhost to a virtual machine using vagrant and the default ubuntu 10.04 64 bit machine. Everything is set up and it almost works, but there is one thing bothering me:

When I run ant and it executes phpunit, I get the following error while executing my selfmade bootstrap:

```
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
```

I could narrow the problem down to the following line of code, which executes the symfony cache:warmup command:

```
executeCommand($application, "cache:warmup");
```

This executes the following command:

```
php app/console -e test -q cache:warmup
```

**Running phpunit without ant works fine**, so does running ant without the executeCommand line.

I read a bit about this stty error and looked up `~/.bashrc`, `~./profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` as well as `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.profile` without finding anything like tty or stty. SO I don't know what I could delete to make it work.

I am a bit stuck as I need the cache warmup and cannot figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a while to figure out, but I now got it.

For some reason, the options passed to the symfony2 application object causeing the issue only when run by ant.
I don't have any insight on what causes it, but changing the command to this fixes the issue:

```
php app/console --env=test --quiet cache:warmup
```

As this is only the long form and does not change anything, I'm very happy. My whole executeCommand function looks like this:

```
function executeCommand($application, $command, Array $options = array()) {
    $options["--env"] = "test";
    $options["--quiet"] = true;
    $options = array_merge($options, array('command' => $command));

    $application->run(new ArrayInput($options));
}
```

The only lines changes are 2 and 3 where the key for the array was changed from `-e`and `-q`. I hope this helps one or another who struggles with an issue like this!